# Changing UILabel text from UICollectionView custom delegate class

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

In my storyboard I have a `UICollectionView`, with cells, sections, etc. I set as delegate and datasource a custom class (so, not the classic myCollectionView.delegate = self) but a custom class that cares about the retrieving of datas.

In this `UICollectionView` I have a label that I need to update with a certain value that I handle in the delegate class. (It's a property of the selected cell).

How can this be done? I read about KVO and Notification, but i'm not sure what I have to do.

More Detail

**MatchCollectionViewController**
In this one:
viewDidLoad
A gameView that act as a container for the  following collectionView
CollectionView declaration (once created the collectionView i add it to the gameView)
The delegate of the CollectionView is the following class CollectionViewUiGrid

**CollectionViewUiGrid**
In this class i implement all the delegate and dataSource methods for the collectionView
initWithFrame (and initWithFrame with my own parameters)
in the method cellForItemAtIndexPath i return an istance of a class (UiGameCell) that extends UiCollectionViewCell

In the method didSelectItemAtIndexPath i have this logic.
If a cell is selected, assign retrieve his property, called CellDescription).
This is the property that i would like to be as my UiLabel value in MatchCollectionViewController.

Comment: Ca you clearly explain hierarchy of your classes.

Comment: it's possible you're looking for the **tag** feature on tables/collections

Comment: I found that using NSNotificationCenter fits the needs.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

As mentioned in 
[Pass object with NSNotificationCenter to other view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8233416/pass-object-with-nsnotificationcenter-to-other-view)

Probably one of the simplest way is to use a NsNotificationCenter.