# Timing of receiving a NSNotification variable in multiple methods in Swift

Tags: swift, nsnotification

I made an `NSObject` class that is receiving a couple of variables from a `UIView` class. I am successfully receiving the variables in the `NSObject` class and am processing them in my method receiveDims, where I append an array of Doubles. When I want to access this array in a second method (serialize), they show up as nil. Some of the research I have done on this suggest that this is a timing issue.

Does anybody have an idea as to why this is showing up as nil and not updating in serialize()? Is there a better way to have these arrays update in serialize()? Pertinent code is below.

```
class PostPath: NSObject {
var points:Array<PostPoint>
var color:UIColor
var width = [Double]()
var height = [Double]()

init(point:CGPoint, color:UIColor) {
    self.color = color
    self.points = Array<PostPoint>()
    let newPoint = PostPoint(point: point)
    points.append(newPoint)
    super.init()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PostPath.receiveDims(_:)), name: "screenWidth", object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PostPath.receiveDims(_:)), name: "screenHeight", object: nil)
}

func addPoint(point:CGPoint){
    let newPoint = PostPoint(point: point)
    points.append(newPoint)
}

func receiveDims(sender: NSNotification){
    if sender.userInfo!["width"] != nil{
        self.width.append(sender.userInfo!["width"] as! Double)
        print("post path width \(self.width[0])")
    }
    if sender.userInfo!["height"] != nil{
        self.height.append(sender.userInfo!["height"] as! Double)
        print("post path height \(self.height[0])")
    }
}

func serialize() -> NSDictionary{
    print(self.width[0])
    let dictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    let cgColor = color.CGColor
    dictionary["color"] = CIColor(CGColor: cgColor).stringRepresentation
    let pointsOfPath = NSMutableArray()
    for point in points{
        let pointDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
        pointDictionary["x"] = point.x!
        pointDictionary["y"] = point.y!
        pointsOfPath.addObject(pointDictionary)
    }
    dictionary["points"] = pointsOfPath
    return dictionary
}
}
```

The class DrawingView is where the width and height variables originate. They are stored to NSNotificationCenter and PostPath.serialize() are called in the following manner (I have trimmed the code to only show these parts):

```
class DrawingView: UIView {

func getDims(){
    self.width = Double(self.frame.size.width)
    self.height = Double(self.frame.size.height)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("screenWidth", object: nil, userInfo: ["width": width])
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("screenHeight", object: nil, userInfo: ["height": height])
}

func resetPatch(sendToFirebase:Bool){
    currentPointPath?.serialize()
}

func addPathToSend(path: PostPath)->String{
    firebaseKey.setValue(path.serialize()) { (error:NSError!, ref:Firebase!) -> Void in
        if let error = error{
            print("Error saving path to firebase\(error)")
        } else{
            pathsInLine.removeObject(firebaseKey)
        }
    }
    return firebaseKey.key
}
}
```

Comment: Theres no code relating to nor any mention of when and where serialize is called. Therefore its impossible to comment, except to say of course its a timing issue as serialize has to be involved after receiveDims, but as already mentioned you show nor describe anything about this

Comment: Can you please show how you are sending your notifications? Your user data might not be getting set correctly, check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35573790/5229157

Comment: Thank you for the followups, I edited my initial post :)

Comment: you will try delegate method that is good. easy way to call in every viewcontroller. at the same time compare than nsnotification run like a timer so drying the battery and some page you will kill the observer will not work in the previous page.